# Angular ng-FitText.js causes Karma tests to fail

Tags: angularjs, plugins, karma-runner

I've followed the very simple installation instructions on http://patrickmarabeas.github.io/ng-FitText.js/ to include FitText into my project.

It's now working fine in the project but is failing Karma tests giving this message:

**Failed to instantiate module myProject due to:**
`Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

If anyone has any suggestions they'd be much appreciated. 
Excluding ngFitText from the application leaves us error-free.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're probably going to need more information.

To have a guess - Angular is simply unable to find the module to load. Even if you are not using the plugin for your testing, Angular will expect all module dependencies to be present. Is it possible that you left the module out of the `files` section of the Karma configuration file, or the path to it is incorrect (ie so Karma isn't including it when running tests)? Karma doesn't know about `<script>` tags in your HTML, so you need to explicitly tell it about any dependencies external to your code when running it.

As an example, one of my Karma configuration files has the following (`bower_components/...` all being external dependencies):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    'use strict';
    config.set({
    ...
    files: [
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
        'bower_components/matchmedia/matchMedia.js',
        'bower_components/matchmedia-ng/matchmedia-ng.js',
        'app/assets/scripts/**/*.js',
        'app/assets/tests/mock/**/*.js',
        'app/assets/tests/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
    ...
    });
};
```

If the above doesn't help then I think you will need to paste your Karma configuration and the full error message and stack trace.

Let me know if you need any more detail.